# Ошибка при заносе данных в бд

Tags: php

У меня проходи регистрация:

```
<p>*Логин: <br><input name="username" type="text" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>*Пароль:<br><input name="password" type="password" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>*Пароль:<br><input name="repeatpassword" type="password" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>e-Mail:<br><input name="email" type="text" size="20" maxlenght="40"></p>
<p>Стартовый покемон:</p>
<p><br><input name='name_poke' type='radio' value='Bulbasaur' class='checkbox' ><b>001 Bulbasaur</b> <br><img src=img/001.jpg width=250 height=190 border=1></p>
```

А чтоб занести это в бд , я делаю так:

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `users` (username,password,email,date,ip) values('$username','$password','$email','$date','$ip')") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("INSERT INTO startpoke(name_poke,img,life,atk,def,exp,type) VALUES('".$_GET['$name_poke']."','".$img."','".$life."','".$atk."','".$def."','".$exp."','".$type."');")     or die(mysql_error());
```

Но в таблицу startpoke мне ничего не заносит =( Помогите пожалуйста !

Comment: В самой базе у поля id как объявлены типы данных?

Comment: int | Primary | AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: а если изменить на так - `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT

Comment: id int(11) No None AUTO_INCREMENT (в phpMyAdmin) а если ещё и добавить его в таблицу уникальных полей вместе с логином? А что mysql_error() сообщает?

Comment: тоже самое. только чёто я не пойму, зачем нам id если мы работаем с name_poke ?

Comment: Вы покажите откуда вы берете значения переменных для занесения их в startpoke

Comment: Стоп, так это нужно создать таблицу pokemon, дальше дать каждому  покемону id,atk,life, и т.п. потом в регистрации в value мы ставим id выбранного покемона и заносим его в таблицу startpoke?

Comment: ну в общем примерно так и есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$_GET['$name_poke'] -> $_GET['name_poke']
```

Для начало это исправьте.